# VSCode appends taskName to msbuild automatically

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code (VSCode) I've create a task to build my c++ project. The build-process is based on Visual-Studio 12.0 projects files create by CMake. It provides configurations for Release/Debug/... modes and I want to create for each configuration a separate task.

**Problem:** VSCode appends the taskName to msbuild automatically. My *tasks.json* file looks like:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "msbuild",
"args": ["${cwd}/build/PROJECTNAME.sln",
         "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"],
"taskSelector": "/t:",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build release",
        "args": ["/p:Configuration=Release"],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
        "taskName": "build debug",
        "args": ["/p:Configuration=Debug"],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }]
}
```

The argument `/t:${taskName}` seems to be appended automatically to `msbuild`. If I add the parameter `/t:Build` in the `args` variable of a task manually, It gives me the error, that two *targets* are specified in msbuild. Removing the `taskSelector` variable does not help. The only way I get it running, is to set all `taskName` variables to `Build`, but then I can not distiguish between different tasks in the tasks-selector.

Any ideas how to solve this?

PS: is there a reference of possible parameters for the tasks.json file, except those provided in the example file and on the official documentation site?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my Grunt tasks. I set the `command` to **grunt**, and and each task, the `taskName` was the target, such as **stage** or **dist**. Code puts them together and executes `grunt stage`. It works, but it's not right. Plus, in the palette, the task name just says "stage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a work item to support suppressTaskName on the task description. If this does get implemented would it solve your problem.

Comment: If `suppressTaskName` means: a new property that can be set to true/ false and has the effect that the *taskName* is appended automatically to the command, or not, respectively, then at least it would solve this particular problem. But a lot of other problems remain. I would love to have commands like in many other software, than can be piped, filled with placeholders and given a description: e.g. for latex compile `latex  %.tex|dvips -o %.ps %.dvi|ps2pdf %.ps` where `%` is a placeholder for the filename. Then add a placeholder for the *taskName* and everyone can append it by them self.

Comment: VSCode doesn't try to come up with its own task runner. The purpose of it is to integrate existing task runners or build tools into VSCode. So in your example above the idea would be that you use make, gulp or msbuild to execute the series of command and then use a tasks.json file to integrate into VSCode. There are also a couple of predefined variables to access the current opened file. They are documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks#_variables-in-tasksjson

Comment: suppressTaskName got implemented and will be available in the next release

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with msbuild command-line arguments I've figured out a workaround. It is not nice and only works in some cases, but for me it is fine. Hopefully in later versions of VSCode a better solution can be implemented.

**The idea**: Add a dummy argument to msbuild, that has no meaningful effect. I've tried two version: (1) add the preprocess command-line switch, that creates a file with content that you could ignore, i.e. `"taskSelect": "/pp:"`; (2) add a dummy property to msbuild that accepts any argument, like `/p:DefineConstants=...`.

The final tasks.json file looks like:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "msbuild",
"args": ["${cwd}/build/PROJECTNAME.sln",    
         "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"],
// a dummy taskSelector to overcome a restriction in msbuild
// (1) "taskSelector": "/pp:",
// (2) ...
"taskSelector": "/p:DefineConstants=taskName_",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build_release",
        "args": ["/t:Build", "/p:Configuration=Release"],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    },
    {
        "taskName": "build_debug",
        "args": ["/t:Build", "/p:Configuration=Debug"],
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]}
```

You can only use *taskName* without spaces, but this is ok, since one can now distinguish between different tasks.

Maybe in other build-systems like grunt there is a similar dummy-parameter that can be set to taskName without changing the build-process.

I'm open to better solutions to this problem.